# If user is logged-in in one browser than if he/she wishes to login in another browser the first seesion should be automatically logged out

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4

I am just trying to use this concept but dont't know , how to do this..

> In Ruby on rails , If user is logged-in in one browser than if he/she
>   wishes to login in another browser the first seesion should be
>   automatically logged out.

Comment: So just overwrite the old session for the user id with the new session.

Answer (score 0):

You can use cookies, which pass the user_id to the server every time there is a request.

Then you can see how many cookies have a user_id that match...

See [Rails and Cookies](http://pothibo.com/2013/09/sessions-and-cookies-in-ruby-on-rails/)